# OSX multiple nswindow inside another

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nswindow

does anybody know how photoshop guys created their panels
I think this is nswindow, But I don’t know how to tie this nswindow to parent window to have a functionality like in photoshop.

Can anyone propose a way to make this ? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `NSWindow` method to tie window to parent:

```
- (void)addChildWindow:(NSWindow *)childWin ordered:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place;
```

Comment: Yes I did it, But it not work as expected. Because when resize parent window - child stay in place.

Comment: Please, explain expected behavior in more details, then. Not everybody can check Photoshop behavior.

Comment: In some area you have a view (NSWindow i think in my case). This view is in MainWindow of the OS X app. You can drag this view out of MainWindow and as a result get the other NSWindow and you can drag this view (NSWindow) back to area and it will be tie to this area when resize, move and etc MainWindow.